# How to launch ios_webkit_debug_proxy using java code

Tags: java, appium-ios

I am able to run Appium server from Java code. But wanted to know how can I
check if iPhone is connected to a Mac and if connected, then launch `ios_webkit_debug_proxy` using Java code

Any pointer or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you havn't installed ios-webkit-debug-proxy install it via homebrew by executing below commands

`brew install ideviceinstaller ios-webkit-debug-proxy`

Once installed you can start it by using Java Process builder and execute it.
Sample [here](https://github.com/sameer49/Appium-Grid-For-Android/blob/master/src/libs/CommandPrompt.java)

Comment: When I try executing using the link which u mentioned, i get error "File/Directory not found"